# How to get information from table

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I have an sql table that has 2 columns, one is id_User from a table named applicationUsers and the other one id_Schedule from the table schedule, when i insert information on them i have to do it by the id, but also i have tha table showed on a datagridview, it shows the 2 colums correct, but how can i get for example i have in the main table 1 1, that the name of the user 1 is David and the name of the schedule is special.

How can i show the name from the user 1(David) and the name from the schedule 1(special) in the datagridview?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to execute a query that joins all three tables, e.g.

```
SELECT u.UserName, s.ScheduleName
FROM User u INNER JOIN UserSchedule us
ON u.UserID = us.UserID INNER JOIN Schedule s
ON s.ScheduleID = us.ScheduleID
```

Populate a `DataTable` from that query and bind it to a `DataGridView` and you'll see the user name and schedule name in the two columns.